# Passing variables (server side / client side ) node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Just starting out with node, express and mongodb (mongoose) and this is what I am trying to do:

1. get parameters from jade file back to index.js via form ✔
2. query the result  in index.js ✔
3. and then return the result back to jade and display it ✖

**search.jade**

```
form(action='/searchByTitle', method='get')
    input(type='text' name ='docTitle' placeholder='Title')
    input(type="submit" value = 'submit')
```

**index.js**

```
...
var Document = require('../models/document');
...

router.get('/search', function(req, res){   
        res.render('search');
});

router.get('/searchByTitle', function(req, res){

    var title = req.param('docTitle');

    Document.find({ title: title }, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
          console.log(doc);
        });         
});
```

in `console.log(doc)` I get a json object:

```
[ { _id: 57b4725b3cd1c8a028a6f686,
    title: 'title123',
    category: 'category123',
    author: 'Anne',
    date: Thu Aug 25 2016 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time),
    version: 1,
    file: 'test.txt',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

How do I pass that object back to search.jade so that i can display it on a page?

I know I can do `res.render('search', {doc: doc});` but by the time it is rendered, page is already being shown.. Do I have to change the routes somehow?

[image: passing values]

Comment: Have you tried a res.json(doc) ?

Comment: It works, it gets displayed in a browser, but my problem is how to display it next to the search form in search.jade..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render  the search.jade once again from  searchByTitle.

```
router.get('/searchByTitle', function(req, res){

var title = req.param('docTitle');

Document.find({ title: title }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err;
      console.log(doc);
      res.locals.doc = doc;
      res.render('search');
    });         
});
```

Then use use the doc in search.jade.

```
form(action='/searchByTitle', method='get')
input(type='text' name ='docTitle' placeholder='Title')
input(type="submit" value = 'submit')
if(doc)
     //render the doc.
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! res.locals is the solution.. thanks!